# REST Design for different actions

Tags: web-services, rest

Say we have a entity called **Timesheet**. For simplicity, let's assume the **Timesheet** entity has three properties (*TimesheetID*, *Status* and *Hours*).

We currently allows the owners of **Timesheet** objects to submit their **Timesheets** via this end point -

```
   POST: /Users/{UserID}/Timesheets/{TimesheetID}
```

With {UserID} currently is the owner of the **Timesheet** object. With {TimesheetID} I can also trace back the owner of the **Timesheet** in the database.

OK, now here is the question -

Now we'd like to have their managers to be able to update the **Timesheet** objects of the employees to that report to them (such as approve/reject **Timesheets** by changing the *Status*, or override *Hours*).

However, there are different levels of Manager Permissions. Some managers are only allow to update *Status* and some of them are allowed to update both *Status* and *Hours*.

Should I reuse the existing end point for both regular user submissions and managers update (I prefer)? Or should I create a different end point for each of the "Manager Level"?

If I hope to reuse the existing end point for all user submissions and manager updates, how do I handle the errors such as if a manager is configured to only update the *Status*, but the **TimeSheet** object posted to the REST service has both *Status* and *Hours* changed. Should I respond with a 403 with a detailed error description to tell the Manager that you can't change the *Hours* property or update the *Status* and ignore *Hours*?

Comment: This is a question which might be better suited to [programmers.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go with `403 Forbidden`. I matches the scenario you describe. [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) says:

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood
> the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to
> make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that
> reason in the response payload (if any).

As an alternative, the server could perform those actions the current user is allowed to and ignore everything else. If this is a good idea depends on your scenarion. I woul prefer to deny the *whole* request and return `403 Forbidden`.

Comment: Thank you. I will go with 403 Forbidden and deny the whole request.

Answer (score 3):

If you're following the [HATEOAS constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS), then a `GET` on the **Timesheet** resource will provide the hypermedia controls (links and forms) that can currently be used to interact with it. While this can be done a number of ways, the one that provides the lowest form of coupling, will include in the form they valid parameters.

For your example, I would include two manager forms with the same endpoint `/Users/{UserID}/Timesheets/{TimesheetID}`. The first one would have a *status* as a required field, the second one would have *status* (*status* could be optional) and *hours* (hours would be required).

You could then either have the second form respond with `403 Forbidden` if the submitter is not permitted to submit hours. Or alternatively, you could filter the forms included in the `GET`, so that only the forms the user is permitted to submit are shown.

**Update**

For example and `GET` on `/Users/1234/Timesheets/24` might currently produce

```
<Timesheet>
    <TimesheetID>24</TimesheetID>
    <Status>Submitted</Status>
    <Hours>40</Hours>
</Timesheet>
```

To apply the HATEOAS constraint, we need to add the hypermedia controls. We'll ignore the URLs for the moment, because they are implementation details. This might give us something like

```
<Timesheet>
    <TimesheetID>24</TimesheetID>
    <Status>Submitted</Status>
    <Hours>40</Hours>
    <link rel="self" href="{{selfUrl}}"/>
    <form id="approve" action="{{approveUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Approve"/>
        </Status>
    </form>
    <form id="reject" action="{{rejectUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Reject"/>
        </Status>
    </form>
    <form id="update" action="{{updateUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Approve"/>
            <option value="Reject"/>
        </Status>
        <Hours type="decimal" cardinality="required"/>
    </form>

    ... there might be other forms too, like ...

    <form id="cancel" action="{{cancelUrl}}" method="DELETE"/>
</Timesheet>
```

What the forms do (and how to recognise a form) are what get's documented in the media type. For instance:

> The `cancel` form on a *Timesheet* resource will cancel the timesheet, updating it's status to "Cancelled". Once a Timesheet has been cancelled, it will no longer be possible to update approve or reject the timesheet.

Also in the media type you would document the properties of the resources. e.g.,

> The *Timesheet* resource has a the following properties:
>
> - *TimesheetID* A unique identifier for the timesheet
> - *Status* The current status of the timesheet. Status may include
>
>   - *Submitted* The timesheet has been submitted, but not approved
>   - *Approved* The timesheet has been approved
>   - *Rejected* The timesheet has been rejected
>   - *Cancelled* The timesheet has been cancelled
> - *Hours* The number of hours (decimal) recorded for the timesheet

While this could be specified by a schema, this should be avoided as doing so can may it very difficult to extent the resources later on. For instance, you might decide to add a "WeekEnding" date property. Existing callers should not care about the new property, which is fine if they are just plucking out the data they are interested in. However, if you've specified the schema without thoughts of extension, then adding properties can cause validation errors in the callers when you add properties.

Now, in terms of who can do what we have a couple of options. One option is to just include all the controls and respond with `403` for any requests made that the caller is not authorised to invoke. Another option is to filter the controls, so they can only see the ones they can invoke. e.g. for the manager that can approve/reject, they might get the following response

```
<Timesheet>
    <TimesheetID>24</TimesheetID>
    <Status>Submitted</Status>
    <Hours>40</Hours>
    <link rel="self" href="{{selfUrl}}"/>
    <form id="approve" action="{{approveUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Approve"/>
        </Status>
    </form>
    <form id="reject" action="{{rejectUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Reject"/>
        </Status>
    </form>
</Timesheet>
```

Whereas a manager that can update the hours might get

```
<Timesheet>
    <TimesheetID>24</TimesheetID>
    <Status>Submitted</Status>
    <Hours>40</Hours>
    <link rel="self" href="{{selfUrl}}"/>
    <form id="approve" action="{{approveUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Approve"/>
        </Status>
    </form>
    <form id="reject" action="{{rejectUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Reject"/>
        </Status>
    </form>
    <form id="update" action="{{updateUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Approve"/>
            <option value="Reject"/>
        </Status>
        <Hours type="decimal" cardinality="required"/>
    </form>
</Timesheet>
```

Alternatively, you can include all the forms for all the users, but add an indicator that they are not authorised to invoke it. e.g. for the manager that can't update hours:

```
<Timesheet>
    <TimesheetID>24</TimesheetID>
    <Status>Submitted</Status>
    <Hours>40</Hours>
    <link rel="self" href="{{selfUrl}}"/>
    <form id="approve" action="{{approveUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Approve"/>
        </Status>
    </form>
    <form id="reject" action="{{rejectUrl}}" method="PUT">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Reject"/>
        </Status>
    </form>
    <form id="update" action="{{updateUrl}}" method="PUT" authorised="false">
        <Status cardinality="required">
            <option value="Approve"/>
            <option value="Reject"/>
        </Status>
        <Hours type="decimal" cardinality="required"/>
    </form>
</Timesheet>
```

I prefer this later approach as you don't end up with support calls for your API, with developers complaining that a particular form doesn't exist. Either way (included or filtered), if the caller invokes a form they are not permitted to, you would still respond with `403`.

A bit off topic, but for completeness, HATEOAS really comes to the fore because it communicates the valid set of hypermedia controls based on the current state of the resource. e.g., when a *Timesheet* has been cancelled, it's not longer valid to approve/reject or update it, so a `GET` on a cancelled *Timesheet* might return

```
<Timesheet>
    <TimesheetID>24</TimesheetID>
    <Status>Cancelled</Status>
    <Hours>40</Hours>
    <link rel="self" href="{{selfUrl}}"/>
</Timesheet>
```

This clearly communicates to the caller that no further actions are permitted on this particular *Timesheet*.

The other thing you'll have noticed is that we haven't actually specified any or the URLs yet. They might all be all the same (e.g. `/Users/{UserID}/Timesheets/{TimesheetID}`) or they might be different (e.g. selfUrl=`/Users/{UserID}/Timesheets/{TimesheetID}`, updateURL=`/Users/{UserID}/Timesheets/{TimesheetID}/update`, etc).

Ultimately the caller should not care as it will use whatever is in the form/link. This provides you with great flexibility as you can change these to suit your implementation needs. For instance, if you are using [Command Query Responsibility Segregation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) (CQRS), it might make sense to send `GET` requests to `//readonly.myserver.com/Users/{UserID}/Timesheets/{TimesheetID}` and `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests to `//readwrite.myserver.com/Users/{UserID}/Timesheets/{TimesheetID}`.

Comment: And, how would a caller know what to do with the two URLs?

Comment: The caller should not care that the URLs are the same. As far as it's concerned there are two separate forms with different purposes. Communicating the purpose of each from can typically be done with an ID attribute and description for each form by ID in the media-type.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, which may be why I've never seen an API that effectively implements HATEOAS.

Comment: Thanks. I've never seen an API return `form` elements before. Is this part of some recent specification?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I know, it is not often seen in the wild, because most people don't grok HATEOAS. It's not part of a recent spec, but from Roy's dissertation whenever he referred to hypermedia or hypertext. Also forms were explicitly excluded from the HAL Draft RFC (see section B.5. at http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-06).

Answer (score 1):

1) You use POST to create, so you can use PUT on the same endpoint to update the data (providing the new data in the content of the request). To limit/log who updates the data you can pass their user/manager ID as a query parameter, or inside the body

2) 403 Forbidden sound better so that it's more clear for the user(manager) what has happened instead of letting him think the data was updated correctly but it was only partially updated actually